# Redirect with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

I have a website with about 2000 links, and other site with the exact same pages.

I need to know how to do in apache the redirect from one domain to the other one, taking into accounts that after the .com the page will be the same on both sites

Example
User request:
www.mydomain.com/product1

Should redirect
www.mydomain2.com/product1

It should be a 301 redirect

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done with **mod_rewrite**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect all requests to www.domain2.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder (or into Virtual Host context) for **www.mydomain.com**. This also assumes that `www.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain2.com` are on **different** servers / virtual hosts (in other words, not pointing into the same physical folder).

Comment: actually both domains are hosted on the same physical folder because its a Magento installation, how would this change the above solution?

Comment: @Luis I have added 1 more line -- it will issue redirect only if URL was requested via `www.domain.com`. You should have mentioned such really important nuance straight away, otherwise any redirect rule will do infinite redirect as both domains do use the same .htaccess and rewrite rules.

Comment: I did this but it didnt work, its a magento site and both domains are on the same server, same physical folder., any idea??

Comment: @Luis Many possible things: 1) Does mod_rewrite works at all? 2) Maybe check the domain name spelling 3) Check Order of rules -- this kind of rule should be on the top, as some specific rules may prevent all following rules from executing at all. 4) Maybe .htaccess in subfolders preventing rewrite rules from parent .htaccess from being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I do this at my company all the time. If you know how to use `mod_rewrite`, turn `RewriteEngine on` and use a `RewriteRule` with the `[R]` flag:

```
RewriteRule www.mydomain.com/product1 www.mydomain2.com/product1 [L,R]
```

[See this site.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I cant rewrite a rule for 2000 pages, there should be an easier way with regular expressions I suppose.